# Find and compress with powershell

Tags: powershell, find, compression

Is there a way to find a folder and compress it to another location?
this is my code

```
Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "D877F783D5D3EF8C"}
```

i have no idea how to convert the result i get and use it to compress the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited a bit to suit your code from [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-zip-archive-of-folder/) blog:

```
$source = ( Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "D877F783D5D3EF8C"} ).FullName

$destination = "Your destination path\zipfilename.zip"

If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive):

```bsh
$folder = Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "D877F783D5D3EF8C"} |Select -First 1

if($folder) {
  Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $folder.FullName -Destination "C:\path\to\new\archive.zip"
}
else {
  Write-Warning "Could not find source directory!"
}
```